# I made a button that opens Google. I have fixed the problem but am wondering why it worked

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a small program (first actually) with Tkinter. This program is supposed to have the logos for websites and when pressed opens the website.

```
google_url = 'https://www.google.com'

def OpenUrl():
    webbrowser.open_new(google_url)

button1 = tk.Button(root, command=OpenUrl)
```

This code functions (after packing/importing everything)

Now this was the code before:

```
button1 = tk.Button(root, command=webbrowser.open_new('https://www.google.com'))
```

I am new to Python so I really want to understand why this change worked. Was it Python interpreter that did something? Now, this isn't all of the code that I wrote so if you think I should show that then ask me but this was the difference that allowed the code to work. (Open Google when the button was pressed. Before, when the code was ran, it opened google but didn't open tkinter)

Comment: The value of `command` is supposed to be the function to be called when the button is clicked, so it is expected to be a reference to a function.  The code "before" was assigned the result of `webbrowser.open_new(...)`, not a reference to a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooray for your first project!

Your first attempt didn't work because the `command` arg must be function. `webbrowser.open_new('https://www.google.com')` is a function **that has already been called** and thusly evaluated. It now equals `open_new()`s return value (which is [nothing](http://webbrowser.open_new)).

The contents of `OpenUrl` are not evaluated until the buttons is clicked, as a function only runs when called. A lambda (an unnamed, in-line function) would work as well:

```
button1 = tk.Button(root, command= lambda: webbrowser.open_new('https://www.google.com'))
```

Happy coding!